# Use setTimeout to resolve or reject a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

I have a code section https://jsfiddle.net/h3m10005/

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
     setTimeout(()=>reject('error'), 5000);
});

p.then(null,(err)=>{
     console.log(err);
});
```

When the above code section gets executed, after approximately 5 secs I will see `error` printed. However, if I dont wrap the reject() call in a function, the console outputs `error` immediately. For example,

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
         setTimeout(reject('error'), 5000);
});

p.then(null,(err)=>{
         console.log(err);
});
```

Any idea why this might be the case? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in your second example you are calling it immediately.

```
setTimeout(reject('error'), 5000);
```

Is essentially using the result of calling reject('error') as the first argument for setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

`()=>reject('error')` and `reject('error')` are completely different. In this case, the first syntax is an equivalent to `function(){ reject('error')}` while calling `reject('error')` without wrapping it within a callback will immediately invoke the function.